# Mobile view looks nothing like desktop

Tags: magento-1.9, mobile

I am brand new to Magento and completely self-teaching.
We have a site for our company using the SM-Shoppystore theme, Magento ver. 1.9.2.4
The problem currently is when viewed on a mobile device, the top banner goes away.
How do I make these show on mobile?

Comment: Can you post a link the live preview of the design for that theme you are using, or your website? I'd guess it's CSS that is set to be hidden in mobile views - but could be something else.